# How to color background in each panel of an xyplot according to a factor variable?

Tags: r, lattice

I'm trying to construct a xyplot which contains different background color according to different values of an additional categorical variable. It is no problem to get repeating background coloring with the panel.xblocks (package: latticeExtra) function, but up to now I found no method to implement this with different coloring for different subplots in the xyplot.

```
JD <- c(seq(0,19, 1), seq(0,19, 1))
VAR <- c(rnorm(20, mean=10, sd=1), rnorm(20, mean=10, sd=1))
CATEG <- c(rep("A", 5), rep("B", 15), rep("A", 10), rep("B", 10))
YEAR <- c(rep(2001, 20), rep(2002, 20))

myd <- data.frame(JD, VAR, CATEG, YEAR)

xyplot((VAR) ~ JD | factor(YEAR), type="l",
       xlab="", ylab="", col=1, data=myd)+ 
  layer_(panel.xblocks(x, CATEG,
                       col = c("lightgray")))
```

Running the above code, the background coloring from the first xyplot-subplot (year 2001) is repeated in the second xyplot-subplot (year 2002). my aim is to get different background coloring according to the varaiable "CATEG" for the two subplots. Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: It's not clear if you want A to be highlighted a different color in each panel or **both** A and B to have different colors in each panel. I suggest an answer that shows both using a `panel` function with the `groups` argument.

Comment: David O, your "Use a different color for each level of 'CATEG' in each panel" using `subscripts` approach was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Glad to hear. This was a puzzle for me a while back and I'm glad you asked this question. I suggested an edit to your question to make it easier for others to find. If the revised question and answer works, consider accepting it to help others find it more readily!

Answer (score 0):

I think the `panel.xblocks` function is a good approach. The use of `subscripts` and `groups` is handy too but always requires some re-learning for me.

The conditioning request (`|`) generates `subscripts`. The `groups` argument is used to pass the `CATEG` values to the panel function. It isn't actually used for any grouping here. The `...` in the panel function is not actually used either, but it's a good practice in case the code is changed and other functions need arguments passed down.

```
# Starting with data in 'myd' from above
# Load non-standard packages
  library(lattice)
  library(latticeExtra)

# Old school colors
  myCol <- c("salmon", "lightgray")
  names(myCol) <- levels(myd$CATEG)

# To use a different color for each level of 'CATEG' in each panel:
  obj1 <- xyplot(VAR ~ JD | factor(YEAR), data = myd,
    groups = CATEG, xlab = "", ylab = "",
    panel = function(x, y, subscripts, groups, ...) {
      panel.xblocks(x, myCol[groups][subscripts])
      panel.lines(x, y, col = 1)
    })

# Here's a solution to a different problem (second plot):
# How to use a different color for the first level of 'CATEG' in each panel 
  obj2 <- xyplot(VAR ~ JD | factor(YEAR), data = myd,
    xlab = "", ylab = "", groups = CATEG,
    panel = function(x, y, subscripts, groups, ...) {
      panel.xblocks(x, myCol[panel.number()][groups][subscripts])
      panel.lines(x, y, col = 1)
    })

# Plot in one device
  plot(obj1, position = c(0, 0.45, 1, 1), more = TRUE)
  plot(obj2, position = c(0, 0, 1, 0.55))
```

[image: panel.xblocks solution and extra example]